# making a relation between two angular projects in the workspace

Tags: angular

How can I make a relation between two projects in a workspace with routing (lazy routing)? 
I can make a relation between a project and a library. 
needless to say, I Create a project with the following command

```
ng generate application name
ng generate library name
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by a relation? Is there anything preventing you from importing the library in the app?

Comment: @ Will Alexander , I said I can use the library in a project, but how can not I use a component in project-1  that It is located in project-2.  don't use a library

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. The components aren't really components once they're in a production build; they're all transpiled to vanilla JS code.

Answer (score 1):

no you cant comunicate two diferent workspaces, once its compiled angular generates html css js code for production, if you want to get information from one project to another you should manually copy the information to files in the project and declare it in the app module, by the way the only thing that is nearly close to that is the option to download npm packages to your project, you could considere that if the information that you are using is a package and not a personalized component